# Removing session for client stored session data

Tags: session, cookies, session-cookies

I am trying to understand how deleting/revoking sessions for a specific user would work in a system where all session data is stored on the browser. If I understand correctly, these systems embed data and a signature in the value of the session cookie. Examples are:

- Go: `CookieStore` in Gorilla Sessions (https://github.com/gorilla/sessions)
- Node: Cookie-session (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-session)
- Ruby: Rails CookieStore (https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1.3/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html)

I believe I understand the concept of how this works and how this is secure. Except for one part:

**How can I ever delete (end, revoke..) a session?** I know that I can invalidate all sessions by changing the keys to create the signature, but what about a specific session?

I understand that I could simply remove the cookie upon a request with that session. But that does not invalidate the value of the session cookie. So if an attacker would have recorded the value of the cookie before I was able to delete it, they would have unlimited access (until the signature key changes). Or is what I am saying completely wrong? What is the approach to prevent this?

**EDIT:**
Perhaps keeping track of all deleted session cookie values is an option. But that would require state on the server side, which seems to negate the benefits this method has. Also, this list might grow a lot as you need to keep track of these until you change your signature keys.